# Set a typescript project in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 Community edition

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea, plugins, ide

Set a typescript project in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 Community edition

I want to set a typescript project in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 Community edition to navigate throught
the classes but I don't see the option in Project Settings - > Facets

[image]

and when I do Ctrl and click in a class I got this message `Cannot find declaration to go`

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 Community edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is supported in Ultimate Edition only: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html